# HTML Canvas Lag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, lag

So I've created a canvas that when you hover your mouse over top of it a green 32x32 box appears. The canvas is very large so you could draw massive portraits, the problem is that drawing the green box has made the canvas and my whole browser laggy.

The part that I added that made it laggy:

```
function makeTileCover(mousex, mousey) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeRect(mousex, mousey, 32, 32);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

I'm guessing that there's some simple answer to fix this, it seems like it might be drawing too many times because the square gets darker the more you hover over it all though I'm not sure that that would fix it anyway.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("MapEditor");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function updateCanvas() {
  container = document.getElementById("container");
  if (container.width != window.innerWidth) {
    container.style.width = window.innerWidth - 250;
  }
  if (container.height != window.innerHeight) {
    container.style.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
}

//Destroy mouse on canvas exit.
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
});

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  var mousex = Math.round(mousePos.x / 32) * 32;
  var mousey = Math.round(mousePos.y / 32) * 32;
  var cursor = document.createElement('canvas'),
    cursorctx = cursor.getContext('2d');

  cursor.width = 32;
  cursor.height = 32;

  makeTileCover(mousex, mousey);

  document.body.style.cursor = 'url(' + cursor.toDataURL() + '), auto';
  document.getElementById('mousePosLocation').innerHTML = "Mouse location:" + "<b id='mousex'>" + mousex + "</b>" + "," + "<b id='mousey'>" + mousey + "</b>";
}, false);

function makeTileCover(mousex, mousey) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
  ctx.strokeRect(mousex, mousey, 32, 32);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas width="16384" height="16384" id="MapEditor"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW I had to reboot after running your snippet. That's an absolutely *massive* canvas. Why do you have one so large?

Comment: your code is fine ... you just need a smaller canvas ...http://jsbin.com/bolizi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: The reason it's so big is that it's going to be a map editor for a game :( same size as their editor.

Comment: My Chrome instance  just  crashed at it ran out memory.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for your canvas to be that big, what will happen if your level is twice that big? Use normal size canvas and implement scrolling inside of it, your performance will jump up hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your canvas is way too big and chrome can't handle the memory required for it. You really never want the canvas to be bigger than what can fit on the screen. (Typically going to be around 1080x1920). Combining that with @ScottMichaud 's answer we get

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <canvas width="1638" height="900" id="MapEditor"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("MapEditor");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var MousePos = {x:0, y:0};
  function updateCanvas() {
    container = document.getElementById("container");
    if (container.width != window.innerWidth) {
      container.style.width = window.innerWidth - 250;
    }
    if (container.height != window.innerHeight) {
      container.style.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
  }

  //Destroy mouse on canvas exit.
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
  });
  function Update(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(Update);
    var mousex = Math.round(MousePos.x / 32) * 32;
    var mousey = Math.round(MousePos.y / 32) * 32;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    makeTileCover(ctx, mousex, mousey);
  }
  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    MousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);

    // var cursor = document.createElement('canvas'),
    //   cursorctx = cursor.getContext('2d');

    // cursor.width = 32;
    // cursor.height = 32;

    // makeTileCover(mousex, mousey);

    // document.body.style.cursor = 'url(' + cursor.toDataURL() + '), auto';
    // document.getElementById('mousePosLocation').innerHTML = "Mouse location:" + "<b id='mousex'>" + mousex + "</b>" + "," + "<b id='mousey'>" + mousey + "</b>";
  }, false);

  function makeTileCover(ctx, mousex, mousey) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeRect(mousex, mousey, 32, 32);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  Update();
```

I also changed the canvas so every frame it refills the canvas to black so you don't get a bunch of squares populating the view and only have the one for where the cursor is.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing way too much on MouseMove, which could fire MANY times per frame, and can occur at ANY time of the frame.

On input events, you want to do as LITTLE as possible.

I think you'd be able to get away with just doing:

```
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
   //I'm attaching it to Window for now. Ideally, you'd use a private namespace.
   window.mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
 }, false);
```

Just set one variable and move on.

Everything else should be associated with the callback triggered by `requestAnimationFrame()`. That way, the mouse position will update with every mouse move, but the draw will only happen once per frame, taking the most recent mouse position.

```
function draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  var mousex = Math.round(mousePos.x / 32) * 32;
  var mousey = Math.round(mousePos.y / 32) * 32;
  var cursor = document.createElement('canvas'),
    cursorctx = cursor.getContext('2d');

  cursor.width = 32;
  cursor.height = 32;

  makeTileCover(mousex, mousey);

  document.body.style.cursor = 'url(' + cursor.toDataURL() + '), auto';
  document.getElementById('mousePosLocation').innerHTML = "Mouse location:" + "<b id='mousex'>" + mousex + "</b>" + "," + "<b id='mousey'>" + mousey + "</b>";
}
```

As an added benefit, good browsers will  will also happen as early in the frame as the browser can manage. This means that your long running code will happen as FAR AWAY from the frame being presented as possible (giving this heavy code the longest time possible to calculate before the monitor needs it, unlike the mousemove event which could happen a fraction of a millisecond before the monitor needs it).

Comment: Also, you can shrink your canvas and implement a scrolling system to see other areas. Currently, you are performing a draw on a 256 megapixel canvas. You'll also want to clear your canvas every frame as well, to avoid stacking draws on draws. Your `draw()` function can also have true/false statements to selectively disable drawing portions that never change, and so forth. You can keep going forever basically, if you can justify the return on effort.